# what are connections need to to be done for tab bar controller in the main window.xib?

Tags: iphone, eclipse, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone-sdk-3.2, tabbarcontroller

help me out with the connections need to be done in the mainwindow.xib for tab bar controller to swith between the tab bar items.
i have connected app delegate to tab bar controller.
But am unable switch over the multiple views when the tab bar buttons are clicked

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have 2 tabs on your tabBarController.

In your appDelegate function

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

  self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

   self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2,nil];

     self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


}
```

This way you can easily bind your tabBarController.
Note: Dont forget to declare tabBarController in your appDelegate.h file.